# Recommend Fourier Analysis Workbook or online examples

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am studying a graduate level course in Fourier Analysis, however my Functional Analysis background is extremely weak, I have also never met Lebesgue Integration and it has been a while since I covered any topology.

I would like the recommendation of a workbook or online course with Fourier Analysis questions at a basic level with solutions, or questions at a more advanced level with thorough solutions.

I'd like something like Kreyszig Functional Analysis but for Fourier, or some online exercises if such a thing is available.

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi is a decent place to start, lots of good exercises.

Comment: @icurays1 does it include solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give a list:

- "Fourier analysis" by T.W. Körner
- Tolstov's little book on Fourier Analysis
- Gerald Folland's book (see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534170943))
- Dym & McKean, "Fourier Series and Integrals"
- E Gonzalez-Velasco, "Fourier Analysis and Boundary Value Problems"
- Stein and Shakarchi, "[Fourier Analysis: an introduction.](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7562.html)"

Comment: Do all of these have worked solutions?

Comment: @fourier1234 Yes, I believe so.